# How to find and click on a button on a website with selenium? (Python 2.7 - Debian)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click on a button, to load more dataes on a website.
I put before and after a time.sleep code part of course to wait a little bit time, but it isn't work.

This button html code looks like this :

```
<button data-mode="arrivals" data-page="-1" data-timestamp="1506584673.386" ng-click="loadMoreFlights($event)" data-current-page="1" data-loading-text="<i class=&quot;fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin&quot;></i> Loading earlier flights..." class="btn btn-table-action btn-flights-load">Load earlier flights</button>
```

And I tried this:

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Load earlier flights')]")
        time.sleep(5)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name = soup2.h2.string
        soup3=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name2 = soup3.h1.string
        soup4=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name3 = soup4.h3.string
        name4 = datetime.now()

        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            temp_data.append(name4)
            temp_data.append(name)
            temp_data.append(name2)    
            temp_data.append(name3)    
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
            datatable.append(newlist)

    time.sleep(10) 
    browser.close()
    return datatable
```

Why is it not working?

EDIT:

Selenium version is : 3.5.0

Firefox version is: 52.3.0

Comment: What exception u r getting

Comment: Thats why i am frustrated now, because i don't get any error, the program is running, but this click event is not working

Comment: Please share the URL and element u want to click

Comment: URL: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/grz/arrivals     ; element/button where i want to click: "Load earlier flights"

Comment: @Mr.D I don't see any click in your code. Do you forget it?

Comment: yes, probably i forget it, because i tried already a lot of different types..now i tried it..unsuccesfully : WebElement clickLoadButton = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Load earlier flights')])) clickLoadButton.click()

Comment: @Mr.D are you using Python or Java? (or both?)

Comment: Only Python2.7 on Debian

Comment: Now i tried this unsuccesfully: we= driver.findElements(By.name("Load earlier flights"))  we.get(0).click()

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: U can click by using javascript then ur problem will solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the path to your button. It should be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Load earlier flights")]').click()
```

Comment: I already tried this code too, and the result the same. Running without error code, but nothing happend :S

Comment: @Mr.D Can you give me the exact URL that didn't click on the button? I tried on https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/grz/arrivals and the button was clicked properly.

Comment: @Mr.D Do you mean the button on your machines was clicked properly?

Comment: I am using a few links (in the urls) i can show this part too if you think here is the problem, but i think its good. My first link is this : https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ams/arrivals

Comment: But here it is not working. Because if i click it (only i want to click once on it) i get more data (earliers data).

Comment: @Mr.D Does it open Firefox? Does it open the URL? Is the button clicked? If the button is not clicked, does it happen on every URL?

Comment: Of course, these links are open in Firefox, but the button is not clicked. And it is happen on every URL.

Comment: @Mr.D Can you add more details about version of Selenium and Firefox in your question?

Comment: Selenium version is : 3.5.0

Comment: Firefox version is: 52.3.0

Comment: I tried this code ONLY 1 URL...and it is working. But if I am trying to read them with my loop there isnt this click event, because the next page is coming without any wait. What can I do? It seems time.sleep(5) totally not working for wait this "event"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working

```
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-table-action btn-flights-load')][contains(text(),'Load earlier flights')]').click();
```